# Pandas - Filtering columns based on value

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe as below. If `sale_done = TRUE` then pass `TRUE` else return `FALSE`

```
id,cust_name,sale_done
1,kevin,TRUE
2,scott,TRUE
3,mark,FALSE
```

I tried the below but get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

```
df['check'] = np.where((df['sale_done'] =='TRUE','TRUE','FALSE'))
```

Comment: You have additional braces, try this: `df['check'] = np.where(df['sale_done'] =='TRUE','TRUE','FALSE')`, also are those strings or booleans in your df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove nested `()`:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df['sale_done'] =='TRUE','TRUE','FALSE')
```

If `True` is boolean:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df['sale_done'],'TRUE','FALSE')
```

If need boolean mask in output - `True` and `False`:

```
df['check'] = df['sale_done'] =='TRUE'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use (if `TRUE` is a string):

```
df['check']=df.sale_done.eq('TRUE')
```

This will automatically return a boolean as desired.

If the `df['sale_done']` are already boolean, it will be same as the column `check`  so you actually do not need it.

Comment: @scottmartin My pleasure. :)